# Turning Image object into BufferedImage object

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

Given an Image object, how do I turn that into a BufferedImage object without using any of the graphics stuff?

Thanks.

(P.S. I'm using Java ImageIO library)

Comment: Which language or library are you using?

Answer (score 5):

As [this article](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/Image2Buf.html?l=rel) (which provides an example of *creating* a BufferedImage from an Image) states:

> An Image object cannot be converted to a BufferedImage object.  The closest equivalent is to create a buffered image and then draw the image on the buffered image.  This example defines a method that does this.